# Should Which Pip and Which Python Return the Same Directory? Zeppelin Configuration On Unix RHEL

Tags: python, unix, pip, redhat, apache-zeppelin

This is probably a really dumb question but I am stuck and wasting too much time on this so I would SO appreciate any help.

I am using a RHEL 7 box and installed Apache Zeppelin on it. Everything works except for the life of me I can't import Python packages such as Pandas.

I realized I didn't have PIP so I installed it with these steps: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ (notice I had to use the "--user" argument for the command "python get-pip.py").

Finally, I did "pip install pandas --user" which worked perfectly. I then go into my Zeppelin notebook and I cannot import pandas, even after restarting the Python interpreter.

I did some research and I think the problem is that "which python" and "which pip" are installed in different directories as the former results in "/usr/bin/python" while the latter in "~/.local/bin/pip".

So I suspect the packages installed with pip are basically getting loaded into a different version of python? If it helps, when I do "whereis python" I get 5 different results such as "/usr/bin/python" and "/usr/bin/python2.7" etc.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to understand is: Python packages aren't installed globally, every installed Python has its own set of packages. BTW, `pip` being a Python package with a script is also not global. If you have a few different pythons you need different pips for them. I don't know Apache Zeppelin so I cannot guess if it uses the system Python (`/usr/bin/python`) or has its own Python; in the latter case you need to install `pip` specifically for Zeppelin so its `pip` install packages available for Zeppelin.

To investigate to what Python `pip` installs packages you need to find out under what python it runs. Start with [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
head -1 `which pip`
```

The command will prints something like `~/.local/bin/python`. If it's not the version of Python you need to install packages for you need to install a different `pip` using that Python.

The most complex case would be if the shebang is PATH-dependent, something like `#!/usr/bin/env python`. In that case `pip` runs Python that you can find with `which python`.

PS. AFAIK the simplest way to install `pip` at RedHat is `dnf install python-pip`.

Answer (score 0):

phd's answer was very helpful but I found that it was just a matter of using the root account to install the python packages. Then my Zeppelin was able to see any packages.